# Is it possible to shorten the delay in a DispatchQueue?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working on a function in Swift that takes a string and translates it into vibrations from a dictionary, with each individual letter having a short delay before the next one is translated.
Here is what I have:

```
let Bz1 = CHHapticEvent(eventType: .hapticContinuous, parameters: [], relativeTime: 0.0, duration: 0.1)

let Bz2 = CHHapticEvent(eventType: .hapticContinuous, parameters: [], relativeTime: 0.3, duration: 0.1)

 let dictionary = [
            "A" : [Bz1],
            "T" : [Bz2],
]
 let message = textLabel.text

 let letterArray = message!.map { String($0) }

 for (index, singleWord) in letterArray.enumerated() {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + Double(index * 1)) {
```

What I have currently creates a roughly 1 second delay between the vibrations of the letters. However, I'm finding the DispatchQueue delay to be too long. I've tried changing the operations and numbers in the deadline, but nothing seems to shorten it. Is there a way to shorten this?

Comment: Configuring a whole bunch of delays in advance simultaneously is a really bad idea. It's better to nest or recurse, starting each delay when previous delay fires. However, instead of `asyncAfter` why not run a repeating Timer? Every time the timer fires, you do the next vibration in the sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GuywithSwift - Why can't you try milliseconds

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .milliseconds(400), execute: {
    })
```